# Sqlite not allow WHERE clause

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am developing one app in which i have make sqlite Database.so there are one table with 3 Field

- 1._id
- 2.Appname
- 3.Rating

For this I need to set Data in Last Field(Rating) with condition where `_id = 1` like this...
but from Post I found that Sqlite not allow where clauses so how can I do this?

```
INSERT INTO Packageinformation(appRating)VALUES (3) where _id=1;
```

can you please help me out this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use update, not insert.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps that's what you need:

```
UPDATE Packageinformation SET appRating = 3 WHERE _id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO inserts data into the database, a WHERE clause is only used for SELECT, which is reading rows.

INSERT INTO with a WHERE clause is nonsense.

If you want to update a row, use UPDATE (see documentation for details).

You could also use REPLACE INTO, but be careful because it might set all other fields to their default values.

Comment: No. Read the SQL docs. INSERT will ADD a record to your database, UPDATE will MODIFY a record. Using WHERE, you can define which record to modify.